# Structure of data returned by SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the structure of the raw data returned by a simple SQL Server query, maybe one like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.p_Foo()
AS
SELECT a, b
FROM Bar;
```

I would expect some kind of key/value structure or 2D array like {{"a", "1"}, {"b", "2"}}. Does SQL Server return JSON? XML? Some proprietary structure? Please forgive my ignorance. I'm used to either SSMS or my application code presenting the result in a neat format.

EDIT: Does the returned data's structure depend on the client? Will it be in one form if running from inside SSMS and another if I call using a library in .NET?

Comment: What is the raw structure of the data returned by Sql Server? Or does it depend on the client?

Comment: SQL Server natively uses [Tabular Data Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/b46a581a-39de-4745-b076-ec4dbb7d13ec) for all communication with clients.

Comment: But is SQL Server actually returning the data using a different structure depending on the client, or is the client translating the data structure it gets back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Tabular Data Stream (TDS) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-tds/1ef08b76-1594-40cf-8ce0-d2407133dd3d

Although the client library you use will abstract that away in to rows and columns, or data tables or objects if you're using an ORM. SSMS displays the result graphically in a grid.